# How can I access FDA drug and medical device recall data from 1970 to 2014?

Tags: data.gov, openfda

The FDA only provides drug and medical device recall data since 2002. As a journalist seeking a more comprehensive data set, I really need to have access to this information.

Comment: Good question - it's not part of the openFDA initiative from what I can tell. I would suggest maybe tweeting at openFDA, US_FDA, and/or FDArecalls.

Answer (score 2):

The process isn't as nice as the API at openFDA, but you can always file a Freedom of Information Act request:  http://www.fda.gov/RegulatoryInformation/FOI/HowtoMakeaFOIARequest/